# How to use redirector.googlevideo.com with Google Drive Videos?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have been looking for a way to get/generate the UNIQUE direct URL, I tried to find it in the Source Code, it does work with the generated link it makes.. But it only gives me the url which is only working on my IP. Some streaming sites I noticed they use redirector.googlevideo.com to generate a UNIQUE link for whoever click it, which then redirect them to the unique link afterwards.

How does I achieve this with Google Drive? Thanks in advance, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: did you find any way ?